# Displaying Multiple Events with the Same Start and End Time in FullCalendar using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am working on implementing FullCalendar in an Angular project, and I'm facing an issue regarding the display of multiple events with the same start and end time on the same day. I am able to display the events but when I'm trying to display 2 events with same start and end time the UI is getting distorted. I am using angular 12 and fullcalendar 5.

I have already tried the default configuration and searched through the FullCalendar documentation, but I couldn't find a solution specific to my scenario.

I am attaching the screenshot of the issue. In the image below these are the two events having same start and end time but these are not looking good. any help please.

Note: This is my first question forgive me for any mistake. Thanks

[image: screenshot of the actual behavior]

I want to display these two events within the calendar's time frame like I have 2 events start time is 6AM and end time is 9AM, but these are not looking well in the UI. I want to fix this UI issue. My events should be displayed with 6 to 9AM time slot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It looks like you have custom CSS in your page. That is the most likely source of the problem, if it causes some conflict with fullCalendar. If you need further help from us, you will have to provide a [mre] of the issue in your question, including relevant code and event data, sufficient that it reproduces the problem when executed. We cannot fix pictures (unsurprisingly). See also [ask]. Thanks.